# Multidimensional session in Magento

Tags: magento

Is it possible somehow to build multidimensional session in magento?
We have

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCounter()
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCounter()
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsCounter()
```

there...
but how to build session like:

```
counter['fb67c36d-03bf-4e89-85e7-077921560b97']
```

Thanks for any response!

Comment: can't you simply set array to the session? Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCounter($arrayGoesHere)?